# Python argparse using a switch to run a if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I make the -c switch not require input? and then if the -c switch is specified when running the test.py script it should run this if statement and create the database. I'm not an expert so I would appreciate a code example.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='test.py', description='Testing Script')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--device', nargs= '*', type=str, help="Device IP")
parser.add_argument("-c", '--createDatabase', nargs= '?', help="Create Database")
parser = menu.parse_args()

if args.c:
    print 'It Worked!, now creating database'

    con1 = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","testing")
    query = con1.cursor()
    query.execute("SET sql_notes = 0; ")
    query.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;")
    con1.commit()
    con1.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [`store_true`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action) action:

```
parser.add_argument("-c", '--createDatabase', action="store_true", help="Create Database")
```

This will make `args.c` default to `False`, and change to `True` if the `-c` option is present.

Comment: Thanks Amber, that solved the first part :)

Still getting this error:
 File "test.py", line 215, in main
  if args.c:
 AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'c'

Comment: Ahh solved it:     if (args.createDatabase != None):

Comment: I meant:  if (args.createDatabase == None):